Лучшая практика реализации undo/redo
Как лучше всего хранить и обрабатывать историю ввода пользователя для undo/redo?
Рассмотрим на условном массиве чисел, где любая операция (добавление нового, удаление одного из существующих элементов, изменение элемента) может повлиять на другие элементы массива.
Например, при добавлении в массив [1,2,7,8] элемента 5, элементы 7,8 должны удалиться, результат операции: [1,2,5].
Варианты решения
Я придумал два варианта хранения истории: хранить историю объекта целиком или хранить историю об операциях.
Например, если хранить объект целиком, получается что-то в духе:
history = [[1,2,7,8], [1,2,5]]
Такой вариант записи удобно восстанавливать, но он занимает много места в памяти.
Если хранить историю об операциях, получается: history = [(('del', 8, 3), ('del', 7, 2), ('add', 5, 2))]. Формат: (операция с элементом, значение элемента, номер элемента в массиве). Такой вариант будет занимать меньше места в памяти (на больших массивах чем в примере), однако сложнее восстановить объект.
Собственно, вопрос
Какой из этих вариантов (или какой-то иной, возможно), вы считаете оптимальным и удобным?

Посмотрите на persistent data structures, persistent array (чаще в приложении к функциональным языкам)

Вы же сами показали, что зависит от размера массива и количества операций. Надо экспериментально смотреть...

Ну да, собственно есть два подхода. Один - это хранить полный срез состояния. Другой - это иметь реализованные операции, позволяющие откатить состояние, и данные для этих операций, и тогда можно хранить эти операции и нужное для них состояние. Это очень актуальная тема для современного System Design.

@Harry ну эксперимент то да, но вдруг есть какой-то способ, который я упустил из виду (предложенный MBo, например)

Есть еще гибридный способ: хранить полное состояние каждые N шагов (для быстрого перехода на нужное состояние без применения/отката всех изменений) и хранить операции для перехода на один шаг назад/вперед (на количество шагов меньше N)
